# Plant identification - similar to ZZ plant, waxy leaves with round fruit

Tags: identification, tropical

Their living condition are bright sun from 8am to 6pm daily, tropical rainfall, 26C to 35C temperature.

[image: p1]

[image: p2]

[image: p3]

[image: p4]

[image: p5]

Comment: Can you slice a fruit in half down the stem?

Comment: the fruit smells very similar to jackfruit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer:

Common name: Happiness Tree / Scientific name: Garcinia Subelliptica.

Apparently, Singapore's NParks has this fabulous website where all the plants and trees grown in the region are listed >>

https://florafaunaweb.nparks.gov.sg/Special-Pages/Record-List.aspx?OptionId=441&DataSourceIDNo=1&CatN=Plant+Characteristics+&+Uses&CatO=Roadside+Tree+%2f+Palm

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably one of the [ficus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus) genus.

But they are so many species... What about
[Ficus Tinctoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ficus_tinctoria.jpg) or [Ficus Fraseri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_fraseri)? Maybe [Ficus Nota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Starr_070727-7677_Ficus_nota.jpg)?

Could also be [Ficus Cyclophylla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_cyclophylla) from Brazil?

Comment: Certainly not Tinctoria, Fraseri, Nota nor Cyclo

Comment: but thanks for the suggestions